# toString return different values

Tags: java

I'm pretty new in java and I'm doing a simple program but I don't know why I get different values, i.e., if I use getX, getY and getZ I get (6,5,8) but if I use toString I get different values for X and Y (3, 4, 8), so can anyone explain me why it happens because as far as I understand it should get the same values in both cases or what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Coordinates {

    private double coorX, coorY;

    Coordinates()
    {
        coorX = 1;
        coorY = 1;
    }

    Coordinates(double x, double y)
    {
        coorX = x;
        coorY = y;      
    }

    void setX(double x)
    {
        coorX = x; 
    }

    void setY(double y)
    {
        coorY = y; 
    }

    double getX()
    {
        return coorX;
    }

    double getY()
    {
        return coorY;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String myString = "(" + coorX + " , " + coorY + ")";
        return myString;
    }

    public class Coordinates3D extends Coordinates{
        private double coorZ;

        Coordinates3D()
        {
            super();
            coorZ = 1;
        }

        Coordinates3D(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            super(x,y);
            coorZ = z;
        }

        public void setZ(double z)
        {
            coorZ = z;
        }

        double getZ()
        {
            return coorZ;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            String myString = "(" + coorX + " , " + coorY + " , " + coorZ + ")" ;
            return myString;

        }

    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Coordinates test1 = new Coordinates(3,4);


        System.out.println(test1.toString());

        System.out.println(test1.getX());
        System.out.println(test1.getY());


        Coordinates3D test2 = test1.new Coordinates3D(6,5,8);

        System.out.println(test2.toString()); ---> here is the problem

        System.out.println(test2.getX());
        System.out.println(test2.getY());
        System.out.println(test2.getZ());


    }

}
```

Comment: you say about using toString, but toString where?

Comment: Add toString() code.

Comment: `Coordinates3D test2 = test1.new Coordinates3D(6,5,8);` is this correct?

Comment: If `Coordinates3D` is inner class than yes

Comment: I have edited the code where I get the problem and I don't understand why or what I'm making wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First there is a problem on how you define the visibility of the fields of the super class:

```
public class Coordinates {
    //defines as private
    //sub classes cannot access to these fields directly
    private double coorX, coorY;
```

This is that you cannot invoke `super.coorX` nor `super.coorY` on any sub class e.g. `Coordinates3D`. So, in `toString` method, when you have this code:

```
String myString = "(" + coorX + " , " + coorY + " , " + coorZ + ")" ;
```

It compiles and runs fine **because `Coordinates3D` is an inner class**. So, when using `coorX` here it's accessing to the value of `coorX` field stored in the instance of `Coordinates` class that created the instance of `Coordinates3D`. This can be easy to replicate if you separate the classes:

```
class Coordinates {
    private double coorX, coorY;
}

public class Coordinates3D extends Coordinates {
    //current code...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //now you will get a compilaton error
        String myString = "(" + coorX + " , " + coorY + " , " + coorZ + ")" ;
        return myString;
    }
}
```

The best solution would be:

- mark the fields in the super class as `protected`
- separate the classes

If you still want to keep `Coordinates3D` as inner class (not recommended), then:

- mark the fields in the super class as `protected`
- use `super.coorX` and `super.coorY` to not have the same unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to the existing answers that even in the class, you should not read the fields firectly, but use their getters.

> ```
>   @Override
>     public String toString() {
>         String myString = "(" + getX() + " , " + getY() + " , " + getZ() + ")";
>         return myString;
>     }
> ```

This also fixes the problem, but you should still not make the `Coordinates3D` class an inner class of `Coordinates`.